# Emacs shell make a new shell in a new numbered *shell<n>* buffer, same window

Tags: shell, eshell

I updated from emacs 27 to emacs 29, and I find that now when I run

`M-x shell`

It overwrites the file/buffer I am currently using with a new shell, rather than starting a new shell in the current window.  What setting can I change to revert to the earlier behavior?

I have the following in my `emacs.d/init.el`

```
(setq pop-up-frames nil)
 (add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist
             `(,(regexp-quote "*shell") display-buffer-same-window))
```

Even `C-u M-x shell` only opens my existing shell, rather than make a `*shell<2>*` as this used to do.

It seems like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70526651/1052117) command no longer makes /new/ numbered shells.

Comment: "It overwrites the file/buffer I am currently using with a new shell, rather than starting a new shell in the current window." No overwriting is done: the window now displays a new buffer (the `*shell*` buffer) rather than the old one: AFAICT, that's expected behavior in either version of Emacs. And FWIW, I cannot reproduce the `C-u M-x shell` behavior: I get new `*shell<N>*` buffers with every use. What happens if you start with `emacs -q`, thereby  bypassing your init file?

Comment: BTW, the link in your last line is pointing to an answer about `display-buffer-alist` which has *nothing* to do with creating shell buffers and processes.